# Can we call a function or a variable from specs file to protractor config file?

Tags: node.js, protractor, syntax-error, config

I have a declaration of a variable in my spec file(app.Login.ts), lets say

```
[Let comment = 'hello']
```

and now this variable (comment), i need to use in my protractor.config.js file. When I'm trying

```
using import { comment } from './e2e/app.Login';
```

i'm getting error saying

```
import { comment } from './e2e/app.Login';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (C:\Users\M220101\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:135:26)
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: You will need to use `require()` since the config is a js file.

Comment: Did you mean import { comment } from require( './e2e/app.Login'); ? I tried but same error

Comment: No, I meant `const comment = require('./e2e/app.Login')`.